# Push ECS Fargate Container logs directly to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, firelens

I have hosted an ECS Fargate cluster that is using the AWS logs driver and pushing logs to CloudWatch, no issues on the awslog driver. Now what I want to do is push the logs directly from the ECS cluster to an S3 bucket.

So I am expecting to use AWS Athena to query the logs from S3. Can Firelens Fluent be the best bet? Please let me know if you guys have any solution to this process.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `Firelens` is the best tool for exporting logs from ECS Fargate to S3 bucket. FireLens works with both Fluent Bit and Fluentd log forwarders. However, I would recommend you to use `Fluent Bit` as it is more efficient than `Fluentd`.

For more information, you can [refer](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-container-log-destinations-fargate/).

Comment: Any other possible ways to push ECS logs to S3 bucket without using a third service or application. ECS Cluster to S3 directly.

Comment: @sam, how do you do that? (ie push ECS logs directly to S3?)

Comment: @grayaii i found task definition example! https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-firelens-examples/blob/mainline/examples/fluent-bit/s3/task-definition.json

Comment: @JongwhoPark, AWESOME!!!! Great Find!!!